# jQueryUI Draggable Helper Option Help

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

Is it possible to modify the clone helper that jQueryUI creates with draggable element?  I don't want the exact clone as the helper, I just want something similar to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the `helper` option, instead of `clone`, use a function that returns a DOM object. Make this object "similar" any way you like. Something like this:

```
$('.selector').draggable({ 
    helper: function(){
        var foo = dom_object_you_create_or_specify;
        return foo;
    }
});
```

References: [jQuery UI Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-helper)